# ForbiddenError: Unable to load OAuth 2.0 transactions from session

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth

I was follow up a tutorials series from [there](http://scottksmith.com/) and kind of stuck at [implementing with oauth](http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/07/02/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-oauth2-server/) part. For the moment, I could generate `code` from beerlocker. but I couldn't able to retrieve token. So far, the error message is

```
ForbiddenError: Unable to load OAuth 2.0 transactions from session
    at transactionLoader (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/oauth2orize/lib/middleware/transactionLoader.js:37:42)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at complete (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:243:13)
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:250:15
    at pass (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:421:14)
    at Authenticator.transformAuthInfo (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:443:5)
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:247:22
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:61:13)
    at BasicStrategy.strategy.success (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:228:13)
    at verified (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport-http/lib/passport-http/strategies/basic.js:91:10)
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/controllers/auth.js:26:16
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/models/user.js:40:5
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/bcrypt-nodejs/bCrypt.js:689:3
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
ForbiddenError: Unable to load OAuth 2.0 transactions from session
    at transactionLoader (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/oauth2orize/lib/middleware/transactionLoader.js:37:42)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at complete (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:243:13)
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:250:15
    at pass (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:421:14)
    at Authenticator.transformAuthInfo (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:443:5)
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:247:22
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:61:13)
    at BasicStrategy.strategy.success (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:228:13)
    at verified (/home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/passport-http/lib/passport-http/strategies/basic.js:91:10)
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/controllers/auth.js:26:16
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/models/user.js:40:5
    at /home/admin/beerlocker/node_modules/bcrypt-nodejs/bCrypt.js:689:3
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Think, you can see on tutorial's comments.

Comment: there're different one thou